# Concatenating select columns of a panda, while ignoring blanks in columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame which looks like this.

```
key A1 A2 A3 BX CX DX
1   X1 Y1    B1 C1 D1
2   X2    Z2 B2 C2 D2
3   X3       B3 C3 D3
4   X4       B4 C4 D4
5            B5 C5 D5
```

I am trying to form a new col 'NC' which is concatenated from columns A1,A2 and A3. If there is no entry in a certain column, the next column needs to step forward.The seperator can be a "," or a "_"

The final df looks like

```
key A1 A2 A3 BX CX DX NC
1   X1 Y1    B1 C1 D1 X1_Y1
2   X2    Z2 B2 C2 D2 X2_Z2
3   X3       B3 C3 D3 X3
4   X4       B4 C4 D4 X4
5            B5 C5 D5
```

If there are no entries in A1-A3, then the entry in NC remains blank.I have looked at other posts in SO and have tried other ways, but I cant seemed to get it right. The entries in A1-A3 columns are floats which sometimes have a 0 after the number(X2.0). I also want to drop the decimal and the 0. Hoping someone more knowledgeable can show me the way.

edit Q to change data type in the data frame

```
key A1  A2  A3  BX CX DX 
1   1.0 2.0     B1 C1 D1
2   3    4      B2 C2 D2
3   7.0         B3 C3 D3
4   5   6.0 7.0 B4 C4 D4
5               B5 C5 D5
```

new df looks like

```
key A1  A2  A3  BX CX DX NC
1   1.0 2.0     B1 C1 D1 1_2
2   3    4      B2 C2 D2 3_4
3   7.0         B3 C3 D3 7
4   5   6.0 7.0 B4 C4 D4 5_6_7
5               B5 C5 D5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter` to filter your columns, and `agg` to join:

```
# Extract columns
v = df.filter(like='A')
# Convert blanks to NaNs so we can call Series.dropna later.
df['NC'] = v[v.astype(bool)].agg(lambda x: '_'.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)
# Or,
# df['NC'] = v[v.astype(bool)].agg(
#                lambda x: x.dropna().str.cat(sep='_'), axis=1)
print(df) 
   key  A1  A2  A3  BX  CX  DX     NC
0    1  X1  Y1      B1  C1  D1  X1_Y1
1    2  X2      Z2  B2  C2  D2  X2_Z2
2    3  X3          B3  C3  D3     X3
3    4  X4          B4  C4  D4     X4
4    5              B5  C5  D5
```

Comment: Can you take a look at the Q again. Changed the data type. thx

Comment: @Acinonyx use `'_'.join(x.dropna().astype(int).astype(str))` inside the lambda function (keeping everything else the same) instead? If that doesn't work, try something simpler: `'_'.join(x.dropna().astype(str))`